# Scanning image using Twain.Dll

Tags: c#, twain, image-scanner

I'm trying to remove the scanner property option. It comes from when I press Acquire button from menu strip. My aim to remove that Scann Property Screen but Can't. Any way to remove that screen? (that form not defined inside project)
project source code at: [C# Scanner Twain](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner)

http://hizliresim.com/zRRk8O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the value of TwUserInterface in TwainLib.cs:

```
TwUserInterface guif = new TwUserInterface();
guif.ShowUI = 0; // hide the user interface of scanner
```